# sorting random numbers sent to child using exec

Tags: c++, c, exec

What I am trying to do is send random numbers generated by a parent and then sent to the child, who then execs "sort -nr", and then sends back the sorted numbers back to the parent. I found this question had already been asked and answered here pretty similar to mine: [how to redirect output of "sort" program from child to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318971/how-to-redirect-output-of-sort-program-from-child-to-parent), and I thought I did everything that it said to get it to work, but I am not able to get the sorting to actually happen. I've even checked to see if it errors out, but I have gotten nothing.

Both Pipes send and receive the same numbers, but they never come out sorted. What Am I missing?

```
int pipe1[2], pipe2[2];
pid_t childID;

if (pipe(pipe1) < 0 || pipe(pipe2) < 0) {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

childID = fork();

if (childID < 0) {      
//Child Process Failure
    perror("fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else if (childID == 0){                                 
//Child Process Instructions
    cout << "Sent Numbers: " << endl;
    //Closes Unused Pipes
    close(pipe1[WRITE_END]);
    close(pipe2[READ_END]);

    //Dups Over the Others, then closes them
    dup2(pipe1[READ_END], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(pipe1[READ_END]);
    dup2(pipe2[WRITE_END], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(pipe2[WRITE_END]);

    int fail = execlp("sort", "sort", "-nr", (char *)NULL);
    cout << fail << endl;
    }
else {                                                  
    //Parent Process Instructions
    //Close Unused Pipes
    close(pipe1[READ_END]);
    close(pipe2[WRITE_END]);

    srand(randSeed);
    cout << "Random Numbers: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < nWorkers; i++){     
    //Generate nWorker numbers, then Write
        randNumbers[i] = rand() % (sleepMax - sleepMin + 1) + sleepMin;
        write(pipe1[WRITE_END], &randNumbers[i], sizeof(randNumbers[i]));
        cout << randNumbers[i] << endl;
    }
    close(pipe1[WRITE_END]);
    wait(NULL);
    cout << "SORTED NUMBERS:" << endl;

    double sortedNumbers[nWorkers];
    int n;

    for(int k = 0; k < nWorkers; k++) {
    n = read(pipe2[READ_END], &sortedNumbers[k], sizeof(sortedNumbers[k]));
    cout << sortedNumbers[k] << ", " << n << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you creating the pipes?

Comment: The protoype of execlp is `int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);`, so it's not going to work with "sort" and "sort" as the first and second arguments.

Comment: I thought "sort" and "sort" as the first two arguments was exactly what you wanted: the first for the name of the program, the second as argv[0]?

Comment: added how I created the pipes, I believe just they are fine, right? And I removed the first "sort", but it still doesn't work. What should be there instead?

Comment: Those are your pipe definitions, but nothing is making them into actual pipes rather than arrays of ints. Also smocking raises a good point; you usually need to give a full path to the executable; it's not like a bash script.

Comment: To be clear, you should be calling `pipe(pipe1); pipe(pipe2);` at the start, otherwise it makes no sense that it's working at all, unless maybe by zero-initialising it's making all your pipes behave as stdin or something.

Comment: You're right, I thought I had put the calls in there. I have edited it and added them. Thanks! I will try the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort(1)` expects its input to be ASCII strings, not raw binary numbers.  When you're passing it the data with `write(2)`, that's writing out the raw binary representation of the numbers to the pipes, which is not what you want.  You need to convert the numbers to their string representations.

One way to do that would be to open a stdio stream on top of the pipe with [`fdopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen).  You could then use `fprintf` to write the formatted data:

```
FILE *childInput = fdopen(pipe1[WRITE_END], "w");
if (childInput == NULL) { /* Handle error */ }
for (...)
{
    ...
    fprintf(childInput, "%d\n", randNumbers[i]);
}
fclose(childInput);
```

Likewise, you need to do the same thing when reading back in the output from the child:

```
FILE *childOutput = fdopen(pipe2[READ_END], "r");
if (childOutput == NULL) { /* Handle error */ }
while (fscanf(childOutput, "%d", &sortedNubers[i]) == 1)
{
    ...
}
fclose(childOutput);
```

Comment: seems to be working, but I am not receiving the numbers back the way they were created:

RANDOM NUMBERS: 12 6 5 9 1 10 1 2 11
SORTED NUMBERS: 6.95314e-310
6.95314e-310
6.95314e-310
3.95253e-323
6.95314e-310
6.95314e-310
6.95314e-310
0
6.95314e-310

Comment: I GOT IT! I randNumbers and sortedNumbers were both set as DOUBLE, and I changed them to regular INT. Now it sorts! Thanks so much!